# How can I use the value of a variable in a method inside another python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the variable `name` inside the method `control_in(self)` which is inside the class `Test`.

I have tried to make `name` an attribute by doing:

a) setattr(control_in,`name`,"Harry Banes")
b) control_in.name = "Harry Banes"

In file b.py I have tried using: 
a) `from a import *`
b) `import a`
c) `from a import Test`
a.a) `print(a.Test.control_in.name)`
a.b) `print(t1.control_in.name)`
a.c) `print(a.t1.control_in.name)`
a.d) `global name` in every part of the code (I know this is useless but just wanted to mention I tried it.)

I have also tried `return name` and `return control_in.name` at the end of the control_in(self) method

and none print the value of the name variable. But everything I put in **init** method, it does print. Take `print(t1.n)` for example that prints: `numbers`.

YES, I've already searched and tried a lot of the solutions other StackOverflow Q&A had and none has worked which is why I am asking personally.

a.py

```
import b

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = "numbers"

    def control_in(self):
        control_in.name = "Harry Banes"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

b.py

```
from a import *

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t1 = Test()

    print(t1.n) # Successfuly prints "numbers"
    print(t1.control_in.name) # Throws attribute error
```

I expect the output "Harry Banes" but instead I get this error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'`

I want to use the value from another Class' methods other than **init**, in another file. Why I want this? Because It's a problem I am having for a way bigger code where I need just 1 variable to make something happen in another function, from another python file but I don't know how to get the variable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `control_in.name = "Harry Banes"` is not a valid code because a class method cannot be referred to just by its name, but by its class:

```
def control_in(self):
    Test.control_in.name = "Harry Banes"
```

or better yet, use `self.__class__` to refer to the class:

```
def control_in(self):
    self.__class__.control_in.name = "Harry Banes"
```

Secondly, `Test.control_in.name` won't be defined until the `control_in` method is called and executed, so you have to specifically call it:

```
t1 = Test()
t1.control_in()
print(t1.control_in.name)
```

This outputs:

```
Harry Banes
```

But lastly, there usually isn't any good reason to add attributes to a function object. In this case the `Test.control_in.name` variable is bound to a class method and is therefore shared across all instances, and should more idiomatically be redefined as a class variable instead:

```
class Test:
    name = "Harry Banes"
```

so that you can access `name` with just `Test.name`:

```
print(Test.name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your educational and straight to the point answer.